# angular material design change color with directive

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular2-directives

I have been trying to change the color of a material design component tho when I put the directive on the component and there was no change, I put it on a html element and nothing happened there too.

heres the service:

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { ColorInterface } from "../core/color.interface"

@Injectable()
export class ColorService {
  // Colors
  private primary: string = "#212121";
  private primaryDark: string = "#000000";
  private primaryLight: string = "#484848";
  private accent: string = "#9e9e9e";
  private accentDark: string = "#707070";
  private accentLight: string = "#cfcfcf";
  private warn: string = "#ffc107";
  private success: string = "#4caf50";
  private danger: string = "#f44336";

  // Set Colors On Load
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject('color') colors: ColorInterface) {
    if(colors) {
      this.primary = colors.primary;
      this.primaryDark = colors.primaryDark;
      this.primaryLight = colors.primaryLight;
      this.accent = colors.accent;
      this.accentDark = colors.accentDark;
      this.accentLight = colors.accentLight;
      this.warn = colors.warn;
      this.success = colors.success;
      this.danger = colors.danger;
    }
  }

  ////  Get Colors  ////

  public get primaryColor(): string {
    return this.primary;
  }
  public get primaryDarkColor(): string {
    return this.primaryDark;
  }
  public get primaryLightColor(): string {
    return this.primaryLight;
  }
  public get accentColor(): string {
    return this.accent;
  }
  public get accentDarkColor(): string {
    return this.accentDark;
  }
  public get accentLightColor(): string {
    return this.accentLight;
  }
  public get successColor(): string {
    return this.success;
  }
  public get warnColor(): string {
    return this.warn;
  }
  public get dangerColor(): string {
    return this.danger;
  }



}
```

What the service does is take a input from the setup module, typically the app module, then it assigns the private variables, so that the only way to call them is through getters.

Heres the Directive:

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, Renderer} from '@angular/core';
import { ColorService } from "../services/color.service";

@Directive({
  selector: '[quiColor]'
})
export class ColorDirective {
  @Input() quicolor: string;

  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef,
    private render: Renderer,
    private color: ColorService)
  {
    if (this.quicolor == "primary")
  this.element.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color.primaryColor;
    if (this.quicolor == "darkprimary")
this.element.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color.primaryDarkColor;
    if (this.quicolor == "lightprimary")
this.element.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor= color.primaryLightColor;
    if (this.quicolor == "accent")
this.element.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color.accentColor;
    if (this.quicolor == "darkaccent")
this.element.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color.accentDarkColor;
    if (this.quicolor == "lightaccent")
this.element.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color.accentLightColor;
    if (this.quicolor == "warn")
this.element.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color.warnColor;
    if (this.quicolor == "success")
this.element.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color.successColor;
    if (this.quicolor == "danger")
this.element.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color.dangerColor;
  }

}
```

Heres the component:

```
<mat-toolbar [quicolor]="'primary'">hello</mat-toolbar>
<p [quicolor]="'primary'">Test 2</p>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<mat-toolbar quicolor [quicolor]="'primary'">hello</mat-toolbar>
<p quicolor [quicolor]="'primary'">Test 2</p>
```

see the example of color directive [here](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-custom-attribute-directive-example) for more details

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't fully fix the problem, but it did through an error which says Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'quicolor' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-toolbar'.

Comment: What I decided to spilt up the directive into multiple directives, this seemed to work

Comment: [] is used to binf to input. I think that you need to use directive without []. try quicolor="primary" or quicolor="'primary'"

Comment: sorry you did it right https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#binding-to-an-input-property